# How to set formula for a entire column by using EPPlus~

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I want to set a formula for entire column in a sheet, but I can not find a way to do so.
Right now I loop a large enough row and set the formula for each cell, but it seems not a good implement.

Is there any right way to deal with this?

Comment: `.Columns.Value = "formula";`? Something similar to that probably

Answer (score 1):

You provide no example or code of what exactly you're trying to do, so I'm not left with much to go off of. I might ID the column and try it doing something like this

```
worksheet.Cells["C27 or could C1: C27"].Formula = "=COUNT(C1: "HOW FAR YOU WANNA GO DOWN")";
```

Answer (score 0):

from memory, I believe you'll want to first define your style in the style dictionary.

Then I'd can apply the style from the dictionary to the cells in the Range. If you apply styling effects  (that have not been defined in the style dictionary) to cells in a range then I believe the style dictionary will then get separate (but same) style entries for every cell in the range you apply the styling to, which will quickly start to suck rocks performance-wise.

But I did this 3 or 4 years ago... EPPlus may do things differently now.